# Issues with Bluetooth and Arduino

Tags: python, windows, bluetooth, arduino

I'm trying to send information from a computer to an Arduino with Bluetooth. I'm using Python for Bluetooth, with the pybluez library, working on Windows.

```
import bluetooth

target_name = "HC-05"
target_address = None

nearby_devices = bluetooth.discover_devices()
print nearby_devices

for bdaddr in nearby_devices:
    print bluetooth.lookup_name( bdaddr )
        if target_name == bluetooth.lookup_name( bdaddr ):
            target_address = bdaddr
            break

if target_address is not None:
    print "found target bluetooth device with address ", target_address
    sock=bluetooth.BluetoothSocket( bluetooth.RFCOMM )

    print "Trying connection"
    port = 3
    sock.connect((target_address, port))
    print "Trying sending"
    sock.send("1 2 3")
    print "Finished sending"
    sock.close()
else:
    print "could not find target bluetooth device nearby"
```

On the arduino side, I'm running the following code.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

//format [motor #][pwmA = 0, pwmB = 0]
const int MOTOR_PINS[5][2] = {{3,4}, {5,6}, {9, 10}, {23, 22}, {21, 20}};
const int SIGN = 1;
String msg = "";

void setup() {  
  Serial.begin(9600); //usb for testing
  Serial1.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  //check for inputs to bluetooth adapter
  while (Serial1.available()) {
   char reading = Serial1.read();
    if ((int)reading == 13 ) {
      Serial.println(msg);
      parseString(msg);
      msg = "";
    }
    else {
      msg += reading;
    }
  }
}
```

(I know the Python port is hardcoded, planning to clean it up later.)

Anyways, when I run the Python code, I successfully find the Bluetooth device. However, I get an error when I try to connect, saying `IOError: A socket operation failed because the destination host was down.` When I open a session with PuTTY to COM3, I can successfully send data to the Arduino (parseString gets called.) I don't understand what the difference is between the two.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe COM3 connected to bluetooth so your Python program can't connect?

Alternately you could use pyserial to connect to COM3. http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/shortintro.html

Answer (score 0):

Okay, thanks for your code to Begin with, by modding it a little I'm able to get what i wanted.

Even i got the same `IOError: A socket operation failed because the destination host was down.` So I first paired my HC-05 with the PC(windows), coz my HC-05 is password locked. Next I started by making a loop which can check for each port between a given range.

Though of not much impact but my suggestion would be to ramp up the serial BAUD @ 115200 for the HC, might just work better.

So the Python code for me looks like this.

```
import bluetooth

#--Pair HC-05 with PC first

target_name = "BLUESAND"
target_address = None

nearby_devices = bluetooth.discover_devices()
print nearby_devices

for bdaddr in nearby_devices:
    print bluetooth.lookup_name( bdaddr )
    if target_name == bluetooth.lookup_name( bdaddr ):
        target_address = bdaddr
        break

if target_address is not None:
    print "found target bluetooth device with address ", target_address
    sock=bluetooth.BluetoothSocket( bluetooth.RFCOMM )

    print "Trying connection"
    #######################################
    i=0 # ---- your port range starts here
    maxPort = 3 # ---- your port range ends here
    err = True
    while err == True and i <= maxPort:
        print "Checking Port ",i
        port = i
        try:
            sock.connect((target_address, port))
            err = False
        except Exception,e:
            ## print the exception if you like
            i += 1
    if i > maxPort:
        print "Port detection Failed."
        exit(0)
    #######################################
    print "Trying sending"
    sock.send("Challange")
    print "Finished sending"
    print sock.recv()
    print "Finished receiving"
    sock.close()
else:
    print "could not find target bluetooth device nearby"
```

And my Arduino Code looks like this.

```
String str;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);     // opens serial port, sets data rate
}

void loop() {
  // send data only when you receive data:
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
      str = Serial.readStringUntil('\n');

      // say what you got:
      Serial.print("I received: ");
      Serial.println("\""+str+"\"");
      //trim the string to skip the trailing CRLF
      str.trim(); 
  }
}
```

Comment: It looks a bit like the answer you provide belongs to a different question / discussion, as you are not the OP but then the topic is ok it seems. Could you add to the answer, something along the lines of: "Having found this question, I was able to implement a solution to a similar problem if mine". Or did I misunderstand the contribution? Please advice or edit. Thanks.

Comment: Actually I could've answered the main question in one sentence stating, change the port number and it will be ok, but someday someone like me lands on this question, they should get an answer which works for them right out of the box. That's what was my thought behind explaining my solution. + had to thank the original author for his/her work.